# SQL Server, cursor never ending

Tags: sql-server, cursor

My task is to make it impossible to add a row that contains wrong form of certain attribute called `pesel`. Firstly I thought I should write a trigger and it worked fine but I was told to change it to cursor because when user want to add many values at once insert will stop at first wrong `pesel` and it won't check the others. So far I came up with this but it seems like it never ends after I execute it.

```
DECLARE cursor_pesel CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT pesel FROM person;

DECLARE @pesel CHAR(11)
DECLARE @WEIGHTS as table (position INT IDENTITY(1,1), weight TINYINT)

INSERT INTO @WEIGHTS 
VALUES (1), (3), (7), (9), (1), (3), (7), (9), (1), (3), (1)

OPEN cursor_pesel
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pesel INTO @pesel

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    IF (LEN(@pesel) != 11 OR (ISNUMERIC(@pesel) = 0))
        RAISERROR('BAD FORM OF PESEL',1,1)

    IF (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@pesel, position,1)) * weight) % 10
        FROM @WEIGHTS) != 0
        RAISERROR('BAD FORM OF PESEL',1,1)
END

CLOSE cursor_pesel
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: By the way, `ISNUMERIC()` might surprise you, and not in a good way :-) For example, `select IsNumeric('1e3')` returns `1`, can you guess why?

Comment: No, but it worked earlier as a trigger, I just have to make it a cursor now

Comment: Why do you think you need a cursor here? This doesn't need to be a cursor, it needs to be an EXISTS query. I see from your comments this is for a class.

Comment: Well... my lecturer was very clear I need to use a cursor here

Comment: Once you finish this class just forget that cursors exist. There are a few administration tasks and mail merge as about the only times a cursor is needed. Otherwise you should write set based logic.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to fetch next records:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pesel INTO @pesel


DECLARE cursor_pesel CURSOR
FOR SELECT pesel FROM person;
DECLARE @pesel CHAR(11)
DECLARE @WEIGHTS as table (position INT IDENTITY(1,1), weight TINYINT)
INSERT INTO @WEIGHTS VALUES (1),(3),(7),(9),(1),(3),(7),(9),(1),(3),(1)

OPEN cursor_pesel

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pesel INTO @pesel

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
BEGIN

    IF (LEN(@pesel)!=11 OR (ISNUMERIC(@pesel)=0))
        RAISERROR('BAD FORM OF PESEL',1,1)

    IF (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@pesel, position,1))*weight)%10
        FROM @WEIGHTS)!=0
        RAISERROR('BAD FORM OF PESEL',1,1)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_pesel INTO @pesel   <--------
END

CLOSE cursor_pesel
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer but the problem remains same, earlier I moved `DECLARE @WEIGHTS as table (position INT IDENTITY(1,1), weight TINYINT)
INSERT INTO @WEIGHTS VALUES (1),(3),(7),(9),(1),(3),(7),(9),(1),(3),(1)` outside of while because when it was inside compilator showed an error `Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type tinyint.`

Comment: well, first problem was a never ending cursor. now let me take a look a second one.

Comment: Has table value only 11 records?

Comment: Yes, `pesel` is CHAR(11) and it is needed to multiply every position

Comment: Ok, I think you don't need a cursor, just let me try one thing.

Comment: Well... my lecturer was very clear I need to use a cursor here

Comment: @Jędrzej for me works fine, check it: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4f7b3607611aead18926305f5a928284)*

Comment: are you sure this is the correct formula? must % 10 be applied to the whole sum instead of value by value?

Comment: yeah it is a correct formula, it worked when I used a trigger but I have to change it to cursor

Comment: could you check with a well-know @pesel value using dbfiddle I've set up.

Comment: you mean the value you declared? it's not the correct value and it should raise an error

Comment: I mean, can you use a value that should returns 0